# No crank or start

Tags: ford, ignition, mustang, no-crank-no-start

I have a 2001 Ford Mustang and I put a new ignition locking cylinder and and a different ignition housing and a new antenna immobilizer and I even have the chipped key attached to the antenna immobilizer and when I turn the key in the ignition the anti theft stops blinking but I get nothing  when I try to.start the car but I get power to everything else I even reset the Remote for the viper alarm system  what can be the problem I don't know what else to do the car was cranking before I put the new ignition housing in now it don't even crank can somebody please tell me what the problem is or what it could be

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Make sure the switch is sending power down the line. Hook up a scantool and make sure that the pcm is receiving the crank request if applicable. Why did you have to replace parts?

Comment: Well the ignition housing was stripped where the locking ignition cylinder goes and I broke my key in half is why I had to replace the ignition locking cylinder and the antenna immobilizer was broke cause I tried to pull the ignition not a smart thing to do at all i know